# Writing logic statements using quantifier

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I was given two predicates $\text{Prime}(x)$ and $\text{Even}(x)$ and is required to write the following statements:

1. For every odd natural number there is a different natural number such that their sum is even.

> My attempt: $(\forall x):(x \in \mathbb{N} \wedge \neg \text{Even}(x) \to (\exists y):(x \neq y \wedge \text{Even}(x+y))).$

and

2. The sum of any two prime numbers except the prime number $2$ is even.

> My attempt: $(\forall x,y):(x \neq 2 \wedge y\neq 2 \wedge \text{Prime}(x,y) \to \text{Even}(x+y)).$

Is my attempt correct? And Am I allowed to write $\text{Prime}(x,y)$ or should I write $(\text{Prime}(x) \wedge \text{Prime}(y))?$

Comment: Prime (x,y) is wrong. Prime( ) is a monadic (unary) predicate.

Answer (score 1):

In the first statement, you wrote $x \neq y \wedge \text{Prime}(x+y)$ but it should be $x \neq y \wedge \text{Even}(x+y).$

Avoid writing $\text{Prime}(x,y)$ because the predicate $\text{Prime}$ only takes one argument (i.e., $\text{Prime}(x)$.)

You could also have written the following.

1. $(\forall x \in \mathbb{N})(\exists y \in \mathbb{N}):[\neg \text{Even}(x) \to (x \neq y \wedge \text{Even}(x+y))].$
2. $(\forall x \in \mathbb{N})(\forall y \in \mathbb{N}):[(\text{Prime}(x) \wedge \text{Prime}(y) \wedge x \neq 2 \wedge y \neq 2) \to \text{Even}(x+y)].$

Comment: That's a careless mistake of myself , sorry! Aside the Prime(x,y) and Even (x+y) my original statement is correct right? And for the statement 2 the question didn't specify the domain of x,y to be natural number, so is it alright if I did not include it? For my tutorial lesson, my tutor told us to write the quantifier according to its position in the sentence so as to not confuse ourselves(but that certainly affects readibility i know).

Comment: Aside that mistake everything is fine! In statement $2$ the domain was not specified but actually it didn’t have to be. Note that a prime number is a natural number itself, so when you say that $x$ and $y$ are prime numbers, you are also saying that those $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers. I just stated the domain to have a more formal and complete expression.

Comment: About the position of the quantifiers, we have to be very careful, but what you did is also right. For example, in statement $1$ I moved the $\exists$ to the beginning of the statement because $y$ (which is the variable bounded to $\exists$) does not appear in he part of the whole expression that is behind $\exists$, so you can move this quantifier to the beginning because it will not affect in this case the meaning of the expression.

Comment: Thanks! But can you illustrate more on the case when the position of the quantifiers will change the whole meaning of the statement? I would like to know more about it.

Comment: There are several examples of that, but let’s note the two statements that we were working with. If in statement $1.$ you decided to move $\forall$ for the position right before the part $x \neq y \wedge \text{Even}(x+y)$, then the variable $x$ that appear inside the scope of the quantifier is bounded by it. Although, the $x$ that is behind would not be bounded by the quantifier. It would be some specific object $x.$

Comment: So moving the for all x quantifier to the part x≠y∧Even(x+y) means that there exist a natural even number x and natural number y, if x is even, then for all x, x+y is even where x is not equal to y. Am I right?

Comment: Moving the $\forall$ would turn the $x$ in $\neq \text{Even}(x)$ a free variable, that’s why it would be different. Your translation is good, but keep in mind that the first $x$ that you are referring it’s not the same that is bounded by $\forall.$ It would be such a strange statement. Virtually, you will never have a statement like that

Comment: In short, about the position of the quantifiers, note that if you have a $(\forall x)$ then all the $x$’s must be in the scope or range of that quantifier, otherwise it would not necessarily be the same variable